# MySQL error when creating a scheduled event

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to add an event to create an entry in the 'dealsArchive' table and then delete the entry from the 'deals' table.  It needs to execute at a specific time.

Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE EVENT testEvent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 HOUR
DO BEGIN
INSERT INTO dealsArchive (did, start, end, tagline, description) SELECT (did, start, end, tagline, description) FROM deals WHERE did=5;
DELETE FROM deals WHERE did=5;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HOUR
DO BEGIN
```

I've tried changing little things about the query, but nothing seems to fix the error.  Why am I getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace that

```
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 HOUR
```

by

```
   ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```